# OpenGL & OBJ: How to fill glcolorpointer with colors from MTL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm parsing an OBJ-file in Android and my goal is to render & display the object. Everything works fine (vertices, textures etc) except the correct color mapping.

OpenGL expects a colorbuffer with rgb-values (+alpha) per vertex into glColorPointer, but the MTL offers three different color-values per material (diffuse,specular,ambient).

Question: How do I compute the expected rgb value for my vertex from these three types of color (diffuse,specular,ambient)? Right now I'm passing the diffusecolor when populating the colorbuffer (this is just a kind of playing around, because of not knowing the solution), the outcome is following:

[link text](http://i56.tinypic.com/24oc6qe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You pass that data to glMaterial, not to glColorPointer. See the [glMaterial reference page (OpenGL ES)](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glMaterial.xml).

Comment: Thanks for the hinting towards the right direction, now I pass these type of data (ambient, specular, diffuse and shininess) PER VERTEX (hope this is correct) into glmaterialfv but now the object is totally white (without any colors). Are there known pitfalls which can be the reason for this behaviour?  My initial setup: gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
 gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);

 gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
 gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);